# Can an empty output for the command aplay -l in the terminal reflect a audio hardware damage?

Tags: 10.04, sound, alsa

The sound on my laptop is not working. I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed. I went through a lot of help over the Internet but nothing helped. Every forum has `aplay -l` followed by

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

and something like this :-

```
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But when I try to do `aplay -l` on my laptop I only get

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

I am not able to find any help on why my laptop returns only this line and other lines are missing. Is it that my hardware is damaged?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Ubuntu does not see any sound device on your system, or it sees one it cannot work with.

From a command prompt do

```
dmesg > msg.out
```

and then

```
gedit msg.out
```

You can scroll through the boot up messages and see what it may say about any sound system.

Historically Linux systems have often had trouble with different types of sound hardware -- on that score Ubuntu is pretty good and usually works well with sound. But if your sound hardware is proprietary or unusual that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware is really damaged, is probably wouldn't even show up in `lspci`. So try that.